# PHP Can't get value textbox

Tags: php, textbox, get

I have table.

```
<tableid="mytable" >
<tr class='row'>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td><input type="textbox" name="txtName" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I used jQuery to add new row

```
var a = $(".row").html();
$("#mytable > tbody:first").append("<tr class='row'>"+a+"</tr>");
```

This is code PHP

```
$_REQUEST['txtName'];
```

I can't get values textbox when create new rows. Please help me

Comment: can't get the values WHERE? php? javascript?

Comment: If you're trying to get the value of txtName in PHP on the same page you're adding to with jQuery, it won't work because PHP has already run its course by the time jQuery runs. If you're posting to the PHP page trying to request the value of txtName, you need to double check that your inputs are inside a form that points to your PHP page.

Comment: Your code creates two textboxes with same name property `txtName`. And because of that it is not giving you result in `PHP`. Refer **Galen's** answer.

Comment: Please close the input tag?

Comment: try explicitly adding tbody in your table..

Comment: Yes. My code creates two textboxes with same name property "txtName". Can you creates two textboxes with different name property.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the html is correct on your server, the reason you can't get the values from new rows is that they all have the same variable name.  Make the name of the input an array.

```
<table id="mytable" >
<tr class='row'>
 <td>Name</td>
 <td><input type="textbox" name="txtName[]"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now all the names will be in the array `$_REQUEST['txtName']`

Also, don't use $_REQUEST. Use $_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, etc.  There are security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the values in PHP probably since you **can't have two text fields with the same name** .

If you're adding a new field dynamically with jQuery, make sure you append a number at the end of some sort, for example *txtName, txtName2, txtName3* etc...

Also, your input markup is invalid, Should be closed:

```html
 <td><input type="textbox" name="txtName" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<tableid="mytable" >
    <tr class='row'>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input type="textbox" name="txtName_0"></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

and each time you need to increment the name values as txtName_1,txtName_2....like that through javascript and then get them as

```
$REQUEST['txtName_0'],$REQUEST['txtName_1'].....or directly use loop them....
```

Comment: Please close the input tag?